# Можно ли обращаться (чтение/запись) к файлам из апплета?

Tags: java, applet

Разбираюсь с апплетами. Написал апплет, который должен сохранять своё состояние. Делаю это с помощью класса `Properties`. Файл свойств находиться по адресу `C:\Users\UserName\.ShapeAppletData\.properties` Когда тестирую апплет в IDE (Eclipse) всё работает. Когда запускаю в браузере (Mozilla) появляется исключение `InvocationTargetException`. Вывел сообщение об ошибке, оно такое:

> acess denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read")

Почему возникает такая ошибка? Может ли апплет обращаться к файлам на компьютере? Как управлять разрешением на чтение/запись апплетом?

UPD :
Локализовал ошибку. Ошибка возникает на этой строчке кода:

```
userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Comment: Представьте какой широкий спектр для работ хакеров был бы, если б через браузер можно было бы лазить по компьютерам бедных юзеров

Comment: Может быть проблема в том, что надо подписать апплет? ммм?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun в свое время постарались сделать технологию апплетов безопасной для конечного пользователя. Обычные Java-апплеты запускаются в песочнице с ограниченными возможностями. Вы можете подписать апплет сертификатом от доверенного издателя и, если пользователь примет сертификат и подтвердит запрос полномочий, запустить его вне песочницы.

В песочнице вам **доступны**:

- сетевые подключения на тот же хост и порт, откуда был получен апплет (у апплетов, загруженных с локальной файловой системы, ограничений нет);
- загрузка HTML-документов
- вызов публичных методов апплетов-соседей по странице;
- чтение системных свойств:

  ```
  java.class.version
  java.vendor
  java.vendor.url
  java.version
  os.name
  os.arch
  os.version
  file.separator
  path.separator
  line.separator
  ```

  и некоторых других при старте через JNLP.

В песочнице в общем случае вы  **НЕ можете**:

- обращаться к файловой системе (доступно через JNLP);
- запускать процессы;
- использовать буфер обмена (доступно через JNLP);
- отправлять задания на принтеры (доступно через JNLP);
- загружать нативные библиотеки (JNI);
- подменять SecurityManager;
- создавать альтернативные загрузчики классов;
- читать некоторые системные свойства:

  ```
  java.class.path
  java.home
  user.dir
  user.home
  user.name
  ```